# Replace values for slice of data based on date_time index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series data and I'm trying to fill some values based on the index which is set to `date_time` as well as another condition based on a state/province. But executing the command is returning an error:

```py
data.loc["Mar 2017" : "Jul 2017" & (data.state == "A"), ["Season"]] = "Summer"

>>>TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [bool] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

But I can do this:

```
prim_data.loc["Mar 2017" : "Jul 2017", "Season"] = "Summer"
```

Is there a way to utilise multiple conditions with the date_time index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `between`:

```
prim_data.loc[df.index.to_series().between("Mar 2017", "Jul 2017") & data.state.eq("A"), "Season"] = "Summer"
```